# Make dump of PostgreSQL database(Windows)

Tags: postgresql

I have a dump file of some DB of `PostgreSQL`. How can I make dump of this database on Windows 7?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: it's on Linux. I asked on Windows

Comment: It's the same on Windows - did you even try?

Comment: Sorry, I understood that it's on Windows too. I've just opened psql, but can't run pg_dump

Comment: @andriy `pg_dump` is a separate command-line program. You run it via the command prompt. I think perhaps you will be more comfortable wit PgAdmin-III. This is off topic for stackoverflow anyway, and belongs on superuser.com